# Custom Stylesheet/Scripts returns a 404 - Wordpress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm bursting my brains out. I just can't figure out why my custom stylesheets/scripts won't load.

The stylesheet/scripts are properly enqueued (see below) but for some reason, if I load the stylesheet on my browser, or check in the browser console. it would return a 404

enqueued via

```
wp_enqueue_style('libraries', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/build/css/libraries.css');
wp_enqueue_style('site', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/build/css/site.css');
```

I have also checked file permissions, and theme and file folders are set to 770.

[image]

[image]

What do you think is the issue?

Comment: `gs-theme` is your child theme or the main theme?

Comment: @VijayHardaha its the main theme

Comment: could be 2 reasons, if you're using the child theme then `get_template_directory_uri()` is wrong you need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` or if you are not using the child theme then the path is wrong, either `build` folder is not there but you used it hard to say without seeing your assets directory files tree.

Comment: @VijayHardaha It does have the proper file structure. See here: https://prnt.sc/i0mtB03JMhPB and this is the parent theme.

Comment: can you try adding a `.txt` file in that css folder and access it by url?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `get_theme_file_uri()` like this:

`wp_enqueue_style ( 'site', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/build/css/site.css'), ... );`

Here the link to the documentation of this function:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/